# how to check multiple of a dynamic number to equal to another dyanami number

Tags: java

```
if (numberContentUnits % 4 == 0 == quantity >= 4){
    getAddToCartMethod(code, quantity);
}
```

here i want check dynamically `numberContentUnits` and `quantity`.i don't want take `4` like static vlaue could please anyone help me...

Comment: what did you mean by **i don't want take `4` like static**

Comment: That doesn't look like valid syntax, I think it should be `if (numberContentUnits % 4 == 0 && quantity >= 4) { ... }`. If I understand your question, just exchange `4` with a variable like `int value = 4` then `if (numberContentUnits % value == 0 && quantity >= value) {...}`.

Comment: can't understand what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand the question exactly, but want to help you. Here is a simple of possible examples from your question:

**Case 1.**

```
public class NewClass2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int quantity = 10;
        int code = 5;
        int four = 4;
        for (int numberContentUnits = 0; numberContentUnits < 50; numberContentUnits++) {
            if (numberContentUnits % four == 0 == quantity >= 4) {
                int res = getAddToCartMethod(code, quantity);
                System.out.println("Res: " + res);
            }
        }

    }

    private static int getAddToCartMethod(int code, int quantity) {
        return code + quantity;
    }
}
```

As you can see you can your "4" *`variable four`) is not static.

**Case 2.**

```
public class NewClass2 {

    static int four = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int quantity = 10;
        int code = 5;
        for (int numberContentUnits = 0; numberContentUnits < 50; numberContentUnits++) {
            if (numberContentUnits % four == 0 == quantity >= 4) {
                int res = getAddToCartMethod(code, quantity);
                System.out.println("Res: " + res);
            }
        }

    }

    private static int getAddToCartMethod(int code, int quantity) {
        return code + quantity;
    }
}
```

Here it is already static. 
What is your question?

Comment: thanks for your answer, actually `numberContentUnits` is `pacakeQuantity` of product for example i will give dynamically `numberContentUnits` is multiples of 1 or 2 or 3...etc and `quantity` also equal to given multiples of `numberContentUnits`.then only user allow to buy the product.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure about the expected outcome of this code.

```
int val = 4; //you have an option of taking this value as method parameter
if ( (numberContentUnits % val == 0) && (quantity >= val) ){
    getAddToCartMethod(code, quantity); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, actually `numberContentUnits` is `pacakeQuantity` of product for example i will give dynamically `numberContentUnits` is multiples of 1 or 2 or 3...etc and `quantity` also equal to given multiples of `numberContentUnits`.then only user allow to buy the product